# Return Object type instead of String type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

```
public interface IApiUserProvider
{
    Dictionary<Guid, string> UserNamesByToken { get; }
    string this[Guid token] { get; }


}

public class ApiUserProvider : IApiUserProvider
{
    private readonly ICacheProvider _cacheProvider;
    private readonly IEntitySet<ApiUser> _apiUsers;

    private string CacheKey
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0}-{1}", GetType().Name, "ApiUsersByToken");
        }
    }

    public ApiUserProvider(ICacheProvider cacheProvider, IEntitySet<ApiUser> apiUsers)
    {
        _cacheProvider = cacheProvider;
        _apiUsers = apiUsers;
    }

    public Dictionary<Guid, string> UserNamesByToken
    {
        get
        {
            return _cacheProvider.Get(CacheKey, () => _apiUsers.Where(u => u.IsActive).ToDictionary(u => u.Token, u => u.Name));
        }
    }

    public string this[Guid token]
    {
        get { return UserNamesByToken.GetValueOrDefault(token); }
    }
}
```

When I replace 
            `string this[Guid token] { get; }`   with
            `ApiUser this[Guid token] { get; }`
I get error in this code as this

```
return string : cannot convert to object


return _cacheProvider.Get(CacheKey, () => _apiUsers.Where(u => u.IsActive).ToDictionary(u => u.Token, u => u.Name));
```

please tell how to convert it to object type

Comment: Can you provide the code for your `ICacheProvider` provider?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must update field **UserNamesByToken**

```
public Dictionary<Guid, ApiUser> UserNamesByToken
    {
        get
        {
            return _cacheProvider.Get(CacheKey, () => _apiUsers.Where(u => u.IsActive).ToDictionary(u => u.Token, u => u));
        }
    }
```

don't forget to update `ToDictionary(u => u.Token, u => u)`

then update your **IApiUserProvider** interface

```
public interface IApiUserProvider
{
    Dictionary<Guid, string> UserNamesByToken { get; }
    ApiUser this[Guid token] { get; }
}
```

and after that update indexer

```
public string this[Guid token]
{
    get { return UserNamesByToken.GetValueOrDefault(token); }
}
```

If this does not help, let me know :)